# flutter BlocProvider Navigation

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc

suppose that we navigate to "PageA" using the following code:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => BlocA(),
        child: PageA(),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

when "PageA" navigates to "PageB". how can I access "BLocA"?
I have tried following code to navigate from "PageA" to "PageB" but it crashes.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => contxt.read<BlocA>(),
        child: PageB(),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to pass an already created bloc to consequent screen you can use the [BlocProvider.value](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocprovider) your code would be like this after the change :

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return BlocProvider.value(
        value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
        child: PageB(),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

PageB should be able to retrieve blocA now.

Comment: BlocProvider has not "value" named property

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have corrected the code.